# Why should use linebreak '\n'

Tags: php, line-breaks

I need some advice ...
I'd like to know if it is a good practice to use in a code line breaks "\n"? What is the purpose?

```
$my_string .= "\n" . "<p>Some values</p>" . "\n";
```

Till now I haven't use it and I'd really like to know ... your opinion.
Thanks

Comment: As the name suggests, it breaks line and shows your Some Values in next line.

Comment: it is a p tag for that, isn't it?

Comment: in the rendered HTML. but a linebreak is for the code itself

Comment: that's what I meant with the question ... I use html tags to display text to be readable in a browser ... but I need addtional '\n' for make code more readable - in which case? I'm sorry as I don't know...

Answer (score 6):

You only need to use "\n" to make the resulting html code neater/easier to read.  It is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The new line makes your generated code easier to read. You might think noone should read your code, however if you run into some problems the generated code is easier to read for debugging purposes as well.

Answer (score 2):

\n can be used when streaming over sockets as well. Sometimes you need to use \r, depending on the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common mistake of the newbie programmers.
They never have an idea that the result of the PHP script execution is plain HTML code.
And sometimes a programmer have to sort things out with that HTML.
While it's just impossible if there are no linegreaks in the code.

Anyway, a good practice would be

```
$my_string = "Some values";
?>
<p><?=$my_string</p>
```

so, you won't need no special linebreaks in the PHP code.

Also, there are some cases where you have to use linebreaks.
For example, if you are composing an HTML email message, you hve to add linebreaks, or they will be forcibly added in the unexpected places.

Comment: um ... I never use the code I gave for example ... it is someone else's and from a very good programmer ... so I thought I missed something out.  Mainly I use it as you showed, but with long php tags

Comment: The reason as I told you in the first statement - one have to read the resulting code sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

at time of writing to break line, means display text after line-break to next line

like enter in some text editor...

Answer (score 0):

The only purpose is for people using the "View Source" feature of the browser - basically no one. While it is considered good practice, I almost never do (because it's pointless) :)

Comment: Why do you think it's considered good practice? It's only really practical when viewing the source code or in conjunction with a `<pre>` tag; there isn't any "good practice" behind it however.

Comment: "basically no one"?! what about yourself?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel And most of us on SO!

Answer (score 0):

for pre-tag (pre formatted text):- http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/f/blfaqpre.htm

so, you can do this in SO

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

\n is just an escape for a new line. An escape is not really required in PHP, but it makes it seamless to output a new line mark.